# Loopback.io anonymous model definitions

Tags: json, node.js, model, anonymous

Is it possible to define anonymous models using the slc tools, or manually in json? For example I have a particular model member and want to have a reusable anonymous 'address' model, but not have that in a backend store, but added directly to the document. Mongoose provides functionality similar to this with no modeled schemas. If this is possible, where in the member.json file would I define this.

```
{
  "name": "member",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "fullname": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": "true",
      "length": "64",
      "doc": "User's full name"
    },
    "displayname": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": "true",
      "length": "64",
      "doc": "User's display name"
    },
    "address": {
      "type": [
        "Address"
      ],
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the "embedsMany" relation type.

```
"relations": {
    "addresses": {
        "model": "address",
        "type": "embedsMany",
        "options": {
        "autoId": false,
        "validate": true
        }
    }
```